# List not recognized as a list anymore when being appended

Tags: python, python-2.7

### Why does the second statement print out "None"? Shouldn't Python simply recognize list-variable loe as a list already, and simply append one more to the list? After all, the first print statement does recognize loe as a list.

```
loe = ["a", "b"]
one = "c"
print "List of elements: ", loe
print "List of elements and one: ", loe.append(one)

------------
Output:
List of elements:  ['a', 'b']
List of elements and one:  None
```

---

Answer (score 1):

list.append() does not have return value. So you got **None**

Comment: Exactly. Many Python operations that you'd think would have a return value (e.g. `list.append`, `set.add`, `dict.update`) return `None`. Python generally doesn't support a [fluent API style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) or *en passant* operations, unlike JavaScript and some other languages.